# What AMP Cache is already available?

Tags: amp-html

What are the methods to to know what AMP Cache is already available?
Do we have links to external resources or tools?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open GitHub bug filed to add a list of all available AMP Caches at https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/10893

Additionally, you can also monitor logs (and/or use something like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri and the new version of that directive) in order to try to quickly catch new caches in order to whitelist them.

Please note whitelisting specific hosts is a huge maintenance effort, and anybody mildly serious can get around it with a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a list of all official caches under this URL: https://cdn.ampproject.org/caches.json

There is also a node library available you can use to get a list of all caches: https://github.com/ampproject/amp-toolbox/tree/master/cache-list.